# Left join with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, left-join

Suppose I have these tables

```
create table bug (
    id int primary key, 
    name varchar(20)
)
create table blocking (
    pk int primary key,
    id int, 
    name varchar(20)
)

insert into bug values (1, 'bad name')
insert into bug values (2, 'bad condition')
insert into bug values (3, 'about box')
insert into blocking values (0, 1, 'qa bug')
insert into blocking values (1, 1, 'doc bug')
insert into blocking values (2, 2, 'doc bug')
```

and I'd like to join  the tables on `id` columns and the result should be like this:

```
id          name                 blockingName
----------- -------------------- --------------------
1           bad name             qa bug
2           bad condition        NULL
3           about box            NULL
```

This means: 
I'd like to return all rows from #bug
there should be only 'qa bug' value in column 'blockingName' or NULL (if no matching row in #blocking was found)

---

My naive select was like this:

```
select * from #bug t1 
    left join #blocking t2 on t1.id = t2.id
    where t2.name is null or t2.name = 'qa bug'
```

but this does not work, because it seems that the condition is first applied to #blocking table and then it is joined.

What is the simplest/typical solution for this problem? (I have a solution with nested select, but I hope there is something better)

Comment: MySQL is preffered, but T-SQL is also OK.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Is it all bugs that either don't have blockers or do have a 'qa bug' blocker?

Comment: Firstly your row 2 won't be returned with NULL because it has a matching row in #blocking. Secondly, what SQL are you using? You have a mysql tag but this is invalid mysql syntax (the '#'), and asides from that your query works in mysql (see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7a93/2)).

Comment: PK is not important for me here (but added some).

Comment: Forget my first statement about row 2; I misunderstood you.

Comment: @StevieG I need all bugs with their qa blockers if there is any (qa blocker). If there is no qa blocker, there should be NULL.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee corrected table names

Comment: @stej - so if a bug has no qa blocker, do you want to see a row for it in the results?

Comment: @StevieG Yes, I want (that's the row with id 2 and 3)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Simply put the "qa bug" criteria in the join:

```
select t1.*, t2.name from #bug t1 
left join #blocking t2 on t1.id = t2.id AND t2.name = 'qa bug'
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to select only one row from `#blocking` and join that to `#bug`.  I would do:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.name as `blockingName` 
from `#bug` t1
left join (select * from `#blocking` where name = "qa bug") t2
on t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 3):

correct select is:

```
create table bug (
id int primary key, 
name varchar(20)
)
insert into bug values (1, 'bad name')
insert into bug values (2, 'bad condition')
insert into bug values (3, 'about box')

CREATE TABLE blocking
(
pk int IDENTITY(1,1)PRIMARY KEY ,
id int, 
name varchar(20)
)
insert into blocking values (1, 'qa bug')
insert into blocking values (1, 'doc bug')
insert into blocking values (2, 'doc bug')


select 
t1.id, t1.name,
(select  b.name from blocking b where b.id=t1.id and b.name='qa bug')
from bug t1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * 
from #bug t1 
left join #blocking t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t2.name = 'qa bug'
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure the inner query only returns one row.
You may have to add a top 1 on it if it returns more than one.

```
select 
t1.id, t1.name,
(select  b.name from #blocking b where b.id=t1.id and b.name='qa bug')
from #bug t1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/414e6/1

```
select
  bug.id,
  bug.name,
  blocking.name as blockingType
from
  bug
    left outer join blocking on
      bug.id = blocking.id AND
      blocking.name = 'qa bug'
order by
  bug.id
```

By adding the "blocking.name" clause under the left outer join, rather than to the where, you indicate that it should also be consider "outer", or optional.  When part of the where clause, it is considered required (which is why the null values were being filtered out).

BTW - sqlfiddle.com is my site.