# mysql select all rows in left and let null in right table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MySql Database, the tables is:

[image]

upper one table is `jenis_pohon` and the lower one is `jtt`

how to select all rows in `jenis_pohon` and join it with `jtt` with condition `jtt.tahun='2016' AND jtt.koperasi_id='4'`

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `jenis_pohon` LEFT JOIN jtt ON jenis_pohon.jenis_pohon_id=jtt.jenis_pohon_id WHERE jtt.tahun='2016' AND jtt.koperasi_id='4'
```

but no luck.

basicaly I want to have 6 rows returned (this 6 rows is come from `jenis_pohon`).

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160991/left-join-with-condition) help?

Comment: @TerryLi awesomeee...exactly what I looking for. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've Created Your tables and tested it, it works.
Use This query :

```
SELECT * FROM jenis_pohon 
LEFT JOIN jtt ON (jenis_pohon.jenis_pohon_id = jtt.jenis_pohon_id AND jtt.tahun = '2016' AND jtt.koperasi_id = '4')
```

Notice that using AND inside join parenthesis make your query mush faster than using WHERE.

The result is :

[image]

You can sort it like :

```
SELECT * FROM jenis_pohon 
LEFT JOIN jtt ON (jenis_pohon.jenis_pohon_id = jtt.jenis_pohon_id AND jtt.tahun = '2016' AND jtt.koperasi_id = '4') 
ORDER BY jenis_pohon.jenis_pohon_id
```

Comment: yes, thank you, I have resolved it using query similar to yours.

Comment: Glad to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below Query.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `jenis_pohon`
LEFT JOIN jtt ON jenis_pohon.jenis_pohon_id = jtt.jenis_pohon_id
AND jtt.tahun = '2016'
AND jtt.koperasi_id = '4';
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://rextester.com/DJYI69864)

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this. Check here [Demo](http://rextester.com/IIRVPR49845)

Table jtt with condition jtt.tahun='2016' AND jtt.koperasi_id='4'
  it returns only 3 records because jtt.koperasi_id='4' ave only 3 records into tabel 'jtt'

```
 SELECT * FROM `jenis_pohon` 
LEFT JOIN jtt ON jenis_pohon.jenis_pohon_id=jtt.jenis_pohon_id 
WHERE jtt.tahun='2016' AND jtt.koperasi_id='4';
```

O Table jtt with condition onlt jtt.tahun='2016'

```
  SELECT distinct * FROM `jenis_pohon` 
  LEFT JOIN jtt ON jenis_pohon.jenis_pohon_id=jtt.jenis_pohon_id 
   WHERE jtt.tahun='2016'
```