# How get the result of mysql query with condition

Tags: php, mysql

teacher table

```
teacher_id      teacher_name
============================
1               john
2               doe
```

student table

```
student_id      student_name    student_score   teacher_id
==========================================================
1               amelia          0               1
2               anderson        0               1
3               fabiano         0               1
4               ronaldo         0               2
5               peter           6               2
6               alex            0               2
```

result

```
teacher_id      teacher_name
============================
2               doe
```

the result is teacher record who one or more of his student score > 0.

How the query of this ?

thanks for the answer and sorry for my bad english

Comment: SQL Basic should help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left join with condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160991/left-join-with-condition)

Comment: Select t. teacher_id,t. teacher_name from teacher t, student s where t.teacher_id=s.teacher_id and s.score> 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple subquery does the trick

```
SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE teacher_id IN
(SELECT teacher_id FROM student WHERE student_score > 0)
```

Also possible is an INNER JOIN

Comment: Why do you use sub query instead of single query with join?

Comment: @e4c5 thanks sir. I have an error with this. I change id with teacher_id before IN statement and it's work great.

Comment: @Milaci out of habit

Comment: glad to have been of help

Comment: for small datasets no difference, but yes @milaci for large datasets subqueries in mysql are slower than INNER JOINs. I use a lot of other dbs postgresql and SQL server but stopped using mysql about 5 years back. On postgresql there's no performance difference between the two. So I am in the habit of writing subqueries because they are more readable. Hope that explains.

Comment: My habit is to pay attention to the performance because i work on huge DB :)

Comment: Good habit @Milaci

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT teacher.* FROM teacher
LEFT JOIN student as student teacher.teacher_id = student.teacher_id
WHERE student.student_score > 0
```

Hopefully this will works for you.